# How do I restore a previously displayed Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the compatibility package v4 in my project and I'm having an issue with keeping a `Fragment` around after it's removed from view. I have my `Activity` displaying 2 fragments...a menu frame on the left, content pane on the right. The menu frame has 3 different menus (Fragments) that can be displayed.

This is how I'm replacing the menu Fragment:

```
public void showMenuFragment( Fragment fragment, String tag ) {

        showFragment( R.id.menu_frame, fragment, tag, false);
        setLastMenuPushed( tag );
    }

protected void showFragment( int resId, Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean addToBackStack ) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if ( fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( tag ) != null && fragment.isAdded() ) {
            transaction.remove( fragment );
        }

        transaction.replace( resId, fragment, tag ).setTransition( FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN ).setBreadCrumbShortTitle( tag );

        if ( addToBackStack ) {
            transaction.addToBackStack( tag );
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

The menu `Fragment`s require data to be loaded before it can be displayed, so I show a loading spinner. Once it's loaded the first time, I want to not have to ever load it a second time unless the `Activity` is finished.

When I call `showMenuFragment(...)` I try to pass in a `Fragment` using `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag)` but it's always `null`, so I have to make a new `Fragment` every time I want to show a different menu.

My question is, how do I keep these `Fragment`s around after they are replaced by other menus? I want to avoid keeping manual references to the `Fragment`s because when the device is rotated, the instance of my `Activity` class is destroyed and I would lose those references.

EDIT: To put in much simpler terms, I want the `FragmentManager` to keep track of previous `Fragment`s without having to add them to the back stack. I don't want to hit the back button and see the previous menu shown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just figured it out. Instead of removing Fragments when I add new ones, I just hide them, then show them when I want to display them again. Here's my modified methods:

```
public void showMenuFragment( Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean addToBackStack ) {

        showFragment( R.id.menu_frame, fragment, tag, getLastMenuPushed(), addToBackStack );
        setLastMenuPushed( tag );
}

protected void showFragment( int resId, Fragment fragment, String tag, String lastTag, boolean addToBackStack ) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if ( lastTag != null ) {
            Fragment lastFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( lastTag );
            if ( lastFragment != null ) {
                transaction.hide( lastFragment );
            }
        }

        if ( fragment.isAdded() ) {
            transaction.show( fragment );
        }
        else {
            transaction.add( resId, fragment, tag ).setBreadCrumbShortTitle( tag );
        }

        if ( addToBackStack ) {
            transaction.addToBackStack( tag );
        }

        transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Looking back on this, I think the better solution was to "detach" the Fragment from the Activity and keep a hard reference to it in the class.

Comment: What would be the advantage of detach vs hide ? Does destroying the view makes a real difference ? Do you have any good way to restore it without reloading the whole fragment ?

Comment: @ben Detach would remove the view hierarchy from the screen, which is a more eco-friendly approach. Most Views do a good job of saving their instance state when removed from a Fragment, so I wouldn't see a big deal there when reattaching.

Comment: attach detach call requires api level 13 is there any alternative way.

Comment: Actually, it appears "detach() the old - add() the new" does the same thing as replace(), i.e. restarts the Fragment's lifecycle with a null instance state Bundle, so that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible. `FragmentManager` takes care ONLY on `Fragments` on his BackStack. But you can workaround the back-button-pressed problem if you let your `FragmentActivity` implement `onBackButtonPressed` and let custom behavior take place. You could delegate them to your `Fragments`, or just show another `Fragment` depending on your App-logic