# WebView return null?

Tags: android, webview

In my program, there are many fragments.

In the `ActionBar`, I have a `SearchView`, and result of the search is displayed in `fragment0`.
When I go to `fragment2` (that does not have `Webview`), I must go back `fragment0` to show results.

However, when I go back to `fragment0` and call the `Webview`, it is null.

What's problem and solution?
Here is MainActivity (where search query is excuted):

```
Fragment fragment0 = new SearchScrActivity();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment0);
ft.commit();
WebView _webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewResult);
```

Here is `SearchScrActivity.java`

```
public class SearchScrActivity extends SherlockFragment {
    private WebView _webView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_screen, container,
                false);
        _webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewResult);
        _webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        _webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        String meaning;
        meaning = "";       
        _webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, meaning, "text/html",
                "utf-8", null);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: not clear to which fragment layout the webview belongs to

Comment: which fragment layout has webview and in which framgent do you want to display the search result.

Comment: R.layout.activity_search_screen. I called it in onCreateView of SearchScrActivity

Comment: so the `webview` belongs to `activity_search_screen.xml` and to the MainActivity Layout?

Comment: yes :) I tried but it webview is null

Comment: So if the webview belongs to the framgent layout and you initialize it in `MainActivity` you get NPE as it does not belong to the current view hierarchy

Comment: Sorry, in my MainActivity I called: `setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);`. In this xml file I have a fragment, and webview in another xml file:`activity_search_screen.xml`

Comment: When you do a `FragmentTransaction` and switch fragments, it destroys the current fragment and removes it from memory. The WebView you created in the fragment will end up getting remade each time. See this question for a good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435632/how-do-i-restore-a-previously-displayed-fragment